# PHP Sessions not working for 1 specific webpage

Tags: php, session

I am creating a website on my raspberry pi. I am using PHP sessions to store data about logged in users. However whenever the user navigates to a different webpage, the session gets destroyed even though it should stay alive until the user closes their browser.
Thanks in advance. If you need any of the code posting, just tell me.

Update:
To create the session I am doing:

```
if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
    session_set_cookie_params(0);
    session_start();
}
$_SESSION["username"] = $user;
$_SESSION["forename"] = $forename;
$_SESSION["surname"] = $surname;
$_SESSION["permlevel"] = $permlevel;
$_SESSION["accesstoken"] = $accesstoken;
header("Location: home.php");
```

And to check if the user is logged in - if a session is running:

```
if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE) {
    echo "User is logged in!";
else {
    echo "User is not logged in."
}
```

Comment: please post a code that how are you checking session ?

Comment: Update: It is not working on any pages.

Comment: You need to start the session on every single page with session_start();

Comment: @joe504860157, yes, you need to start a session in a page before checking session.

Comment: @michael if I start a session on every single page, will all of the sessions still hold the same values? e.g. in login.php: '&_SESSION['a'] = 'hello';' and then If I did 'echo $_SESSION['a'];' it would echo hello?

Comment: yes, it is maintaining the same value. session_start() Start new or resume existing session. yes, it will print "hello".

Comment: session_start — Start new or resume existing session -- from php.net. Yes, it will remain the same values if it's worjing correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Your first line should be `session_start();`

Please make sure this and try again.

So the the code for webpage will be like

```
<?php
        session_start();

        // Your existing code here;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this to check

```
<?php
session_start();
if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE) {
    echo "User is logged in!";
else {
    echo "User is not logged in."
}
<?
```

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the issue. Thankyou for all of the suggestions and the time you spent helping me. The issue itself was not the php sessions, but the database. There was an issue with the mysql databse that made it return null values all the time meaning that all the values stored in the $_SESSION[] were null.